# Ternary operation returning "Undefined Property"

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I have switched from using this ternary operation to if/elseif/else, but I would really like to know why this doesn't work.  I keep getting the error:

> ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined property: stdClass::$error

If I were to switch the order of the conditions so that the `$res->response` piece was 3rd, then I get the same error but for that property instead.  It makes no sense to me, and testing it on Codepad.org (which uses PHP 5.2) it works as expected:  http://codepad.org/gwteijIe

Here's the test code in question:

```
$output = '{"error":{"message":"This is a test error"}}';
$res = json_decode($output);

$error = isset($res->response) ? $res->response->message :
     isset($res->error) ? $res->error :
     isset($res->error->message) ? $res->error->message :
     $output;

echo $error;
```

(The reason why it checks for `$res->error` and `$res->error->message` is because the API we're using will return any one of the three conditions we're checking for.  Disclaimer: it's not my API!)

Any insight as to why I am not getting the results I expect?  Many thanks in advance for the help.

**Edit:**

To clarify, this is what I am trying to achieve:

```
if (isset($res->response))
{
    $error = $res->response->message;
}
elseif (isset($res->error->message))
{
    $error = $res->error->message;
}
elseif (isset($res->error))
{
    $error = $res->error;
}
```

Comment: What version of PHP is this running on?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help downvoting a nested ternary.

Comment: It's not a nested ternary.

Comment: That is indeed a nested ternary. It's considered bad practice to nest ternary in the way you are doing it. Write it out and I'm sure the problem with become clear.

Comment: Maybe this is where my problem is coming from then... I'm not nesting anything here.  I'm just checking if each condition is true or not, and assigning the value accordingly.

Comment: Btw, it does work on 5.3; see [this codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Gf4DFw)

Comment: When you place one ternary inside of another ternary, that is considered a nested ternary. So, for example: `(condition 1 ? true : (condition 2 ? true : false))`, the second condition is nested within the first. You have a ternary nested in a ternary nested in a ternary.

Comment: It's becoming clear that my understanding of ternary operations is quite incorrect.  I was under the impression that they were a shorthand way of writing if/elseif/else statements, but I think I finally get it now.  Thank you all for setting me straight ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't nest ternary operator.

You see the error because of the order in which ternary operators are evaluated; it would be far better and more maintainable to just write it out like this:

```
if (isset($res->response)) {
  $error = $res->response->message;
} elseif (isset($res->error)) {
  if (isset($res->error->message)) {
    $error = $res->error->message;
  } else {
    $error = $res->error;
  }
} else {
  $error = $output;
}
```

Your old code evaluates like this; even then it's non-obvious what really happens:

```
((isset($res->response) ? $res->response->message :
isset($res->error)) ? $res->error :
isset($res->error->message)) ? $res->error->message :
$output;
```

See also: [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#example-121)

Comment: This is basically what I ended up doing.  But I don't know why the ternary doesn't work.

Comment: @DondeEstaMiCulo The second part of my answer shows you how your code is actually evaluated.

Comment: Interesting.  I don't understand why it would evaluate it like that though.  Is it because I have too many conditions?  From what I understood, ternary operations were just a shorthand replacement for if/elseif/else.

Comment: @DondeEstaMiCulo The ternary operator evaluates from left to right, whereas `if/else` uses branching to clearly delineate each value to assign.